# Loading CSVs Periodically using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, csv, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to load multiple CSV files each 5seconds for updating some displays in Google Maps API v3, but only loads one or two, never all the files.

Here is the code:

```
setInterval(function() {
        checkLaneStatus();
        initMap();
    }, 2000);


    function checkLaneStatus(){
        laneStatus('landing_lane.csv',landing_lane);

        laneStatus('landing_curve.csv',landing_curve);  

        laneStatus('arrival_lane_1.csv',arrival_lane_1);    
        laneStatus('arrival_lane_2.csv',arrival_lane_2);    
        laneStatus('arrival_lane_3.csv',arrival_lane_3);    
        laneStatus('arrival_lane_4.csv',arrival_lane_4);    

        laneStatus('t1.csv',terminal1); 
        laneStatus('t2.csv',terminal2); 
        laneStatus('t3.csv',terminal3); 
        laneStatus('t4.csv',terminal4); 

        laneStatus('departure_lane_1.csv',departure_lane_1);
        laneStatus('departure_lane_2.csv',departure_lane_2);    
        laneStatus('departure_lane_3.csv',departure_lane_3);    
        laneStatus('departure_lane_4.csv',departure_lane_4);    

        laneStatus('departure_curve.csv',departure_curve);

        laneStatus('departure_lane.csv',departure_lane);
    }

    function laneStatus(file,lane){
        var temp = lane;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: file,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {processData(data);}
        });
        function processData(allText) {
            console.log(allText);
            var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
            var entries = allTextLines[0].split(',');
            if(entries[2] != -1){
                temp.setOptions({strokeColor: colorRed, fillColor: colorRed});
            }
        }
    }
```

CSV file example (id,name,status): If the status is -1 means that the lane is free any other number means that is busy.

```
1,'Departure Lane 1',-1
```

The supposed behavior is: Loading same csv and update display colors, so should check all csv for detect changes. But it only loads one csv each interval, so only that "lane" is updated.

laneStatus function receives the location of the csv that are located in the root (same folder of the index.html where the code is executed). "lane" argument is a google.maps.Rectangle object.

I guess that I explained well, would appreciate any reply!

Thanks!

Comment: i don't see where the data from each request is given to the maps, you just seem to sometimes set some color options. also, you need to call init() only once, or else it will reset your previously-loaded markers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely hitting your browsers max simultaneous request limit. Because you cannot control your end-users browser config what about implementing a simple queue that is just a first in first out array.  Add each request to the queue, and have a second interval that creates one of those requests every 500 milliseconds or so until the queue is empty.

If you are in control of the data could you combine some of the files with one more column for what lane it corresponds to?  Or even write a simple middleware layer that combines them, it would speed up the page quite a bit as it only has to open the one connection.

I also like using web sockets (socket.io) if you are going to pull data that often as it keeps a persistent connection across requests.